# WPM formula doesn't work

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-1.4

I'm using the following code to calculate WPM (words/minute), CPM (chars/minute), CPS (chars/second) and Accuracy in a typing software.

```
//wpm
global.wpm = global.total_words / runtime_min;

//cpm
global.cpm = global.total_chars / runtime_min;

//cps
global.cps = global.total_chars / (runtime_min/60);

//accuracy
global.accuracy = 100 -((global.total_wrongChars*100)/global.total_chars);
```

Accuracy works, but the other spit out too high numbers, like 2843.1565 when it should be 1

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom variable at the create event

```
global.step_counter=0;
```

And increase it every step

```
global.step_counter+=1;
```

Then you can use in your code like this

```
//Steps / steps per second / seconds
var duration = global.step_counter / room_speed / 60

//wpm
global.wpm = global.total_words / duration;

//cpm
global.cpm = global.total_chars / duration;

//cps
global.cps = global.total_chars / (duration/60);

//accuracy
global.accuracy = 100 -((global.total_wrongChars*100)/global.total_chars);
```